# How to gather the name of the files in each subdirectory in a separate list

Tags: python

Let's say /test has subdirectories /test1, /test2, /test3 and so on, and each has multiple PDF files inside.

I would like to save PDF files name for each subdirectory in a separate list with Python

How can I do this?

I try the below code:

```
import os
PDF_list = []
for r, d, f in os.walk('.'):
    for outPDF in f:
      if outPDF.endswith('.pdf'):
         print(outPDF)
         PDF_list.append(outPDF)
```

but with this code, I can save all the PDF files that I find in this list. 
but for me I want to save the PDF file in each subdirectory in a separate List

How Can I do that please ?

Comment: Add the code what you tried.

Comment: Does `os.walk()` do what you want?

Comment: What if there are no PDF files in some folder. Should we append an empty list or ignore it?

Comment: we can ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires just a small change. Create a list for each subdirectory and then, if it's not empty, append it to your main list:

```
import os

pdf_lists = []
for path, directories, files in os.walk('.'):
    pdfs_in_directory = []
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfs_in_directory.append(file)
    if pdfs_in_directory:
        pdf_lists.append(pdfs_in_directory)
```

For the following directory structure:

```
- /test
   - /test1:
      - file1.pdf
      - file2.pdf
   - /test2:
   - /test3:
      - file3.pdf
      - foo.txt
   - /test4
      - bar.txt
```

it will give you:

```
[['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf'], ['file3.pdf']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path = "/path/../temp/"

files = [os.listdir(path + i) for i in os.listdir(path)]

pdfs = []
for pdf in files:
    for j in pdf:
        if j.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfs.append(j)
```

Example:

```
- /temp
  - /temp1
    - x.pdf
    - y.py
  - /temp2
    - z-pdf
    - w.pdf
```

The above code will give you result as:

```
['x.pdf','z.pdf','w.pdf']
```

Comment: with this, I will get only list of subfolders name in each  folder and not the files name too

Comment: If in the path u specify the path to test folder it will work eg - '/home/meryem/test/'

Comment: No I find all the files not only PDf files

Comment: Just check now it will result all the pdfs

Comment: @Shyam , Thank you so much for the help that u provide to me and for your reply

Comment: @Meryem you're welcome. btw this solution should also work for you

Comment: It is  working if I don't have a file in the main directory, otherwise I get an error :)

Comment: But in the question you have mentioned that you just want to have list of files in sub directories. Should I update my answer with including files in main directory as well?